# Linux cross-compile fails with undefined reference to `__emutls_v._ZSt11__once_call' during linking

Tags: c++, linux, docker, mingw, cross-compiling

I want to use cross-compile on docker to create Windows binary.
Docker based on Buster Debian with g++-mingw-w64 package.
My project uses protobuf/grpc. gRPC isn't cross-compile ready - I mean grpc_cpp_plugin.exe is obviously Windows binary. But with binfmt_misc help building process move further.
To skip error about lack of std::mutex I used `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-posix` as C++ compiler.

Now - during linking I'm seeing this awful message

> /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld:
>   /root/.conan/data/protobuf/3.6.1/bincrafters/stable/package/bb20affd9c58e6b3954ccc151546a38faf759db9/lib/libprotobufd.a(common.cc.obj):common.cc:(.rdata$.refptr.__emutls_v._ZSt11__once_call[.refptr.__emutls_v._ZSt11__once_call]+0x0):
>   undefined reference to `__emutls_v._ZSt11__once_call'
>   /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld:
>   /root/.conan/data/protobuf/3.6.1/bincrafters/stable/package/bb20affd9c58e6b3954ccc151546a38faf759db9/lib/libprotobufd.a(common.cc.obj):common.cc:(.rdata$.refptr.__emutls_v._ZSt15__once_callable[.refptr.__emutls_v._ZSt15__once_callable]+0x0):
>   undefined reference to`__emutls_v._ZSt15__once_callable'

I copied `c:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\7.3.0\libstdc++.a` into docker and force linkage with this (add LDLIBS="-l/var/run/gcc_libs/libstdc++.a" during CMake project configuration). Now it complains about `undefined reference to`std::__once_functor'`.

How to solve problem of **undefined reference to `__emutls_v._ZSt15__once_callable'**?